# moving background-image on mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make effect that background image moves on mousemove. Now the image does not move, just stay same. Also, I think there is an error on script but I couldn't figure out which part is wrong.

```js
/* background movement by mouse*/

$(document).ready(function() {
  var movementStrength = 25;
  var height = movementStrength / $(window).height();
  var width = movementStrength / $(window).width();
  $("#top-image").mousemove(function(e) {
    var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
    var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
    var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
    var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;
    $('#top-image').css("background-position", newvalueX + "px     " + newvalueY + "px");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img id="top-image" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/4164/landscape-mountains-nature-mountain.jpeg">
</div>
```

Comment: You add image tag on your html and you tried animate with background-position that's not make sense. Can you please make sure first what really you want to do and what you are trying currently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not using a background image, I don't think you're affecting anything to try to modify the background-position property.  Also, I would base the movement amount on the image dimensions, not the window dimensions.  Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
                 var movementStrength = 25;
                 var img = document.getElementById('top-image');
                 var imagewidth = img.clientWidth;
                 var imageheight = img.clientHeight;
                 var height = movementStrength / imageheight;
                 var width = movementStrength / imagewidth;
                 $("#top-image").mousemove(function(e) {
                   var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
                   var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
                   var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1;
                   var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1;
                   $(this).css("margin-left", newvalueX + "px");
                   $(this).css("margin-top", newvalueY + "px");
                 });
               });
```

```css
#top-image {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  padding-top:20px;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 380px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
TITLE
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img id="top-image" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/4164/landscape-mountains-nature-mountain.jpeg">
</div>
<div>
Some More Text
</div>
```

Comment: Unless the rest of the page is absolutely positioned, I don't think this will work. The whole body will be moved.

Comment: If you make the container bigger than the img than you'll be fine.  https://jsfiddle.net/9gme82zb/11/